# How can I configure an Anaconda environment to pull specific packages from separate custom channels

Tags: python, anaconda, config

I can configure an Anaconda environment with a yaml-file to be pulling packages from several named channels, eg.

```
name: test1
channels:
  - anaconda
  - conda-forge
  - plotly
  - pytorch
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - pytorch::pytorch
  - conda-forge::nodejs>=12.8.0
  - plotly::plotly-orca>=1.2.1
  - pip:
    - objgraph
    - setproctitle
```

This works fine.

However, we are using mirrored channels with custom urls. We can easily pull packages from these custom channels, but cannot use channel-name::package-name syntax in dependencies because now the channels are not named. This does not work, because the custom channels does not have names:

```
name: test1
channels:
  - http://xyz.local:8080/conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge
  - http://xyz.local:8080/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
  - http://xyz.local:8080/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2
  - http://xyz.local:8080/conda.anaconda.org/plotly
  - http://xyz.local:8080/conda.anaconda.org/pytorch
  - nodefaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - pytorch::pytorch
  - conda-forge::nodejs>=12.8.0
  - plotly::plotly-orca>=1.2.1
  - pip:
    - objgraph
    - setproctitle
```

Is there a syntax for naming custom channels?

Regards Niels Jespersen

Comment: Now raised as issue on Anacondas Github as well. https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/anaconda-project/issues/259